# Is it possible to run Vertex AI Workbench on Spot machines?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm trying to save budget on jupyter notebooks on Google Cloud but couldn't find a way to run Vertex AI Workbench (Notebooks) on spot machines.
What are my alternatives?

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is **no**; the better answer is: **you have an alternative**.

Vertex AI Workbench is indeed a managed service with Compute Engine VM as the underlying infrastructure. However it doesn't support Spot/Preemptible instances.

Instead you can quickly install a [deep/machine learning image](https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm) on a VM using a Google's images.  See [this detailed tutorial](https://www.tensorops.ai/post/almost-free-jupyter-notebooks-on-google-cloud).

Deep Learning VMs don't support launching from the GCP Console and more features like co-coding. But it does support Spot/Preemptible instances and doesn't introduce a management fee. So you get lesser experience but also pay less.